# How to upload a book to server selected from iBooks from my iPhone Application?

Tags: ios, ibooks

I wanted to upload a pdf selected from iBooks from my iPhone application. Just like selecting a photo from gallery and uploading it. Is there any classes just like UIImagePickerController for selecting a book from ibooks ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do something like that. Simply because the content is not something that is free.